# Selecting multiple rows out of a second table for every row in a first table

Tags: mysql, sql

**The Idea:**
I have two tables: a table of dates (CALENDAR) and a table of locations (6 locations total). I would like to do a select statement that joins the two tables together such that I a get 6 rows per date, where each date row is duplicated for each location. For example, if I'm selecting August 21, 22, and 23 from CALENDAR for the locations 'New York', 'Spain', and 'Michigan', I want the returned rows to look like:

```
August 21 - New York 
August 21 - Spain
August 21 - Michigan
August 22 - New York
August 22 - Spain
August 22 - Michigan
August 23 - New York
August 23 - Spain
August 23 - Michigan
```

**The Problem:** I only have limited SQL experience so I don't know how to do this kind of join. Can anyone provide a code sample which would replicate the same behavior?

Comment: *such that I a get 6 rows per date* - I think I understand what you are looking for, but your output example is not 6 rows per date.

Comment: It's ok, problem has been solved. I was lazy and didn't want to write out 18 rows so the sample I gave only used 3 locations. A little confusing in retrospect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a join at all - there's no relation between the two tables. So...

```
Select Date, Location
FROM Calendar, Locations
```

Comment: Had to do a group by, but works like a charm. Did not know this about this syntax. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can do an inner join with a condition that is always true

```
select t2.date, t2.city from t1
inner join t2 on 1 = 1
```

or do a cross join

```
select t2.date, t2.city from t1, t2
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for you.

```
mysql> select * from tempcity,tempdate where tempcity.jcity in ('New York','Spai
n','Michigan') and tempdate.jdate in ('Aug 21','Aug 22', 'Aug 23') order by temp
date.jdate;
```

tempcity is table- which has jcity column.
tempdate is table- which has jdate column.